# How to add two different objects in array list to rest API request using Rest Assured?

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I want to add payload like this:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "saumy",
            "code": "say1y"
        },
        {
            "name": "saumy",
            "code": "say1y"
        }
    ],
    "dispositionList": "11379"
}
```

I have successfully able to add

```
 {
        "name": "saumy",
        "code": "say1y"
    }
```

but I am  not able to get how to add comma separated next array list.

In step definition i have added the first using:

```
@Then("Uses the token and create Bulk disposition status payload with {string} {string}")
    public void uses_the_token_generated_and_created_bulk_disposition_status_payload_with(String name, String code)
            throws IOException {
        randomName = name + randomNumber;
        datajson = new Data("CODE", "CODE123");
        res = given().spec(requestSpecification()).body(data.addDispositionStatus(randomName, code, listId, datajson))
                .relaxedHTTPSValidation();
    }
```

What can be added to add the next array list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the official docs here [Rest-Assured: multi-value parameter](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#multi-value-parameter)

Create an arrayList (of objects) and add your objects to it.

Example:

```
Data data1 = new Data("code", "code123");
Data data2 = new Data("otherCode", "code456"); 

ArrayList payloadData = new ArrayList();
    payloadData.add(data1);
    payloadData.add(data2);


given().body(payloadData).then().statusCode(200);
```